# as_Spatial Error when converting sf object to sp

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp

I am working on the example for as_Spatial which is giving me the following error :

**Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = from$wkt) :
unused argument (SRS_string = from$wkt)**

```
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
spdf <- as_Spatial(nc)
as(st_geometry(nc), "Spatial")
```

both codes for transforming from sf to sp gives the same error

Comment: What are the version of sf and sp you're using? You can use `sessionInfo()` to check.

Comment: That code runs just fine for me on a Windows 10 machine, running R-4.0.3 **sf** 0.9-6 and **sp** 1.4-4 (the latter loaded via a namespace).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I updated my **sp** package to 1.4-4 and then i got the following error.

_Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = from$wkt) : 
  no arguments in initialization list_

Comment: @rw_11 My best advice is to install up-to-date versions of R (currently at R-4.0.3) and all spatial packages (using `update.packages()` to get the latest of versions of all installed packages). Coordinate reference system handling code in the open source world has been undergoing a once in a generation overhaul in the year plus since R-3.6.1 was released, and you'll really want to be using the most up-to-date versions of everything (and at least **sp**, **sf**, **raster**, and **rgdal**), to ensure that all the pieces are working together as well as possible.

Comment: To add to @JoshO'Brien 's recommendations, `{sf}` is the successor to `{sp}`, and any operation you do in `{sp}` should also be possible in `{sf}`. So unless you're using the `sp` object in functions from other packages which require it, I would recommend staying with the `sf` object.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thank you. It solved my problem.

Comment: @SymbolixAU thanks. I have a doubt here. I have computed the area using `st_area` and now want to remove those polygon whose area are below certain threshold within the `sf` object. How to do that

Comment: an `sf` object is a `data.frame`. So you filter it as you would any other data.frame. In base R this would be something like `sf[ sf$area < my_threshold, ]`

Answer (score 0):

Your codes run fine in my Windows 10 computer. Also, comments provided above should work. However, you can try this:

```
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc_sp <- as(nc, Class = "Spatial") # converts sf object to sp object
```